# Stability factor and stiffness of voltage divider on a transitor

Tags: voltage, current, bias, common-emitter, base

Does stability factor and stiffness of the bias network have a connection? [this](https://www.petervis.com/GCSE_Design_and_Technology_Electronic_Products/Potential_Divider/Potential_Divider_Bias.html) site mentioned something about stability factor so i was wondering if its thesame thumb rule about the current in network being greater than the base current by a magnitude of 10

Comment: Stability of what? Thermal stability? Part variation stability? Something else? In any case, sensitivity analysis is what tells you the answer to any of these questions.